# UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT while performing a transaction on ether.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, web3js, hardhat

i get this issue while trying to deploy the olympusDao smart contract on rinkeby using hardhat

```
Error
cannot estimate gas; 
transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit 
[ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] 
(
    reason="execution reverted", 
    method="estimateGas", 
    transaction={
        "from":"0xBDA87452eDD9c15D0EEA25120410f329fEAA2D78",
        "to":"0x1DeB9157508316A24BC0527444B142f563705BD0",
        "data":"0xec78f90b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
        "accessList":null
    }, 
    error={
        "code":-32000,
        "message":"execution reverted"
    }, 
    code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, 
    version=providers/5.6.6
)
```

steps to reproduce

- git clone https://github.com/OlympusDAO/olympus-contracts.git
- yarn install
- uncomment "// rinkeby: getChainConfig("rinkeby")" from the hardhat config file
- yarn compile
- yarn deploy:rinkeby

the error comes up on the last script 100_post_deployment.ts when it attempts a transaction